# Alternative to application pool startMode="AlwaysRunning"

Tags: iis-7

If a web application called for itself to be setup with it's application pool to be configured in the applicationHost.config as:

```
<add name="AppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
```

Would the same result be achieved by just requesting a page from the server every minute? Or does setting startMode to this value have other implications also?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be the same. Seemingly, since Microsoft saw developers having to do this, they created this new feature to automatically handle this.

> [Developers] then either devise custom scripts to send fake requests to the application to periodically “wake it up” and execute this code before a customer hits it, or simply cause the unfortunate first customer that accesses the application to wait while this logic finishes before processing the request (which can lead to a long delay for them).
>
> ASP.NET 4 ships with a new feature called “auto-start” that better addresses this scenario, and is available when ASP.NET 4 runs on IIS 7.5 (which ships with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2).  The auto-start feature provides a controlled approach for starting up an application worker process, initializing an ASP.NET application, and then accepting HTTP requests.

From Scott Guthrie's [Auto-Start ASP.NET Applications (VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 Series)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).

So unless you're not using IIS 7.5, I'd say just use the built-in functionality.

(And thanks; I didn't know about this feature, but can definitely think of sites that I develop for that could use it.)

Comment: It's a damn shame they created this feature at the applicationHost.config level. It should be instead at the web.config level.

Answer (score 4):

IIS 7.5 includes an additional flag on a Site or Application level called `preloadEnabled`. Setting this to true will create a fake request to warm up the site. It must be used in conjuncation with `autoStart`.

**autoStart**

```
<add name="{yourapppoolname}" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
```

**preloadEnabled**

```
<site name="YOURSITENAMEHERE" id="4″>
  <application path="/" applicationPool="YOURAPPPOOL" preloadEnabled="true">
  <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\YOURSITENAME" />
  </application>
</site>
```